# MYSQL Concat with PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I'm trying to do some MYSQL Concat with PHP script because I like to add a PHP conditions on it but it's not working.

```
'concat("<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"", sup.sup_id, "" "\" name=\"supplier_id[]\" <?=(in_array(\", sup.sup_id,"" "\", $suppliers) ? \"checked\" : \"\") ?> >") AS Select"');
```

The checkbox without the PHP script is working properly, but when I added the script,the script is not working. And the checkbox is displaying `>` beside it.

I think I'm having trouble closing the script, what is the correct way to make this working??

**EDIT**

Here are some details

```
$select = array('sup.sup_name AS "Company Name"','suppro.suppro_price AS "Price"',
            'concat("<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"", sup.sup_id,"" "\" name=\"supplier_id[]\" <?=(in_array(\"", sup.sup_id,"" "\",$suppliers) ? \"checked\" : \"\") ?> >") AS "Select"');
        $where = array('prod.pro_id' => $item_id);

        $result = $this->canvas->getItemCanvas($select, $where, 'crts_products prod');
        $actions = array();
        $total_rows = 0;

        $this->_data['suppliers']       = $suppliers;

        $this->_data['flashsuccess']    = $this->session->flashdata('msg');
        $this->_data['pr_id']           = $pr_id;
        $this->_data['item_id']         = $item_id;
        $this->_data['qty']             = $qty;
        $this->_data['header']          = 'Canvas Company for Item<br><small>'.$item_name.' QTY: '.$qty.'</small>';
        $this->_data['listing']         = table_listing('user',$result, $total_rows,$offset, $this->_limit, $actions, 3, false,'','');
        $this->_data['form_url']        = user_url().'canvas/save_canvas/';
        $this->set_template('user/canvas/begin',$this->_data, 'user');
```

Here's the working screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUjWW.png)
But when I added the PHP script inside concat, here's what it looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Aa5.png)

Comment: What does this output as in your browser? and/or can you show the PHP outputting of this?

Comment: why you going for concat?can you post some more details or code.

Comment: You are attempting to output php code in the concatenated string? Ie that you hope will be processed by php?

Comment: I see 2 times where you have `"" "\"` in the string. the first time is in `"" "\" name=\"` in which 2 double quotes which appear aren't being escaped. the second time is `sup.sup_id,"" "\",`, likewise 2 sets of double quotes appear aren't being escaped. though i would have to question why you are using MySQL to concat PHP/HTML code because i can't see your `in_array` PHP working to my knowledge since it's now a string you have to echo out

Comment: Hi guys, I edited my post and added more details, hope you can help me, thanks! @Tristan, yes that's what I'm attempting

Comment: You need to use `eval()` to execute the php code in the string otherwise it will be echoed to the browser as a string - which is what appears to be happening.